# How to efficiently copy properties from an object to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I'm looking for a way to write this code in a more efficient way. In the object load method it will have as many lines as entries in **options** (at least).

```
var myPlugin = {
  // here are the 'plugin' default ptions
  option1: 'deafult1'
  , option2: 'deafult2'
  , option3: false
  , option4: true
  , optionN: 'deafultN'

  // here the plugin will receive an object ('options')
  load: function(options){
    if (options.option1) myPlugin.option1 = options.option1;
    if (options.option2) myPlugin.option2 = options.option2;
    //...
  }
}


myPlugin.load({
  option3: true
  , option5: '123'
});
```

Is this the proper way to load options to a JS/jquery plugin?
Is there a way to use a `for ()`/`each()` to load the **options object** in a more efficient/neat way?

I thought something like:

```
  load: function(options){
    $.each(options, function(index, opt){
      // how to load options from here?
      // something like:
      // myPlugin.  ->current opt property name = opt

   });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `$.extend()`

`var opts = $.extend( {}, myPlugin.options, options );`

That will copy properties from right to left, with the rightmost object receiving the highest priority.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: ok. But myPlugin doesn't have an 'opts' object. all the options are direct to the plugin: `myPlugin.option1` not `myPlugin.opts.option1`

Comment: Okay. Well, you could copy directly onto `myPlugin.options` with `$.extend( myPlugin.options, options )` – depending on how you use `myPlugin` this may or may not cause problems due to the fact that you'd be overriding the defaults every time you `extend()`.

Comment: worked for me like this `$.extend( myPlugin, options );`. But I'm considering putting all options in an object like `myPlugin.options`, will that be more safe/logical?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at `$.extend` from [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/).

It is an easy way to copy properties across objects or to a new object entirely.
For example, from jQuery website:

```
var defaults = { validate: false, limit: 5, name: "foo" };
var options = { validate: true, name: "bar" };

// Merge defaults and options, without modifying defaults
var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );`
```